# Argument 3 cannot convert from dtologinModel class to dtologinmodel[] in syncfusion blazor

Tags: .net-6.0, syncfusion-blazor

Getting error on moving cursor to class showing obj is not null here.

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<dtoLoginModel>> LoginUserNew(dtoLoginModel obj)
    {
       return  await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<dtoLoginModel[]>(BaseUrl + "Login/LoginUserNew", obj);
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<dtoLoginModel>> LoginUserNew(dtoLoginModel obj) 
{ 
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<dtoLoginModel[]>(BaseUrl + "Login/LoginUserNew", new dtoLoginModel[] { obj });
    return response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<dtoLoginModel>>(); 
}
```

Is this working??